# JQuery Mobile and Scala.js: How to call functions like "navbar()" or "toolbar()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, jquery-mobile, scala.js

In JQuery mobile, to make persistent headers, footers and nabbers work as expected, you have to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "[data-role='navbar']" ).navbar();
    $( "[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']" ).toolbar();
});
```

What is the equivalent in Scala.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual in Scala.js, as a first "draft" you can always use the dynamically typed API:

```
js.Dynamic.global.$("[data-role='navbar']").navbar()
```

If you want a statically typed API, you can define it. As far as I know, no one has written facade types for jQuery mobile yet. However, there are facades for jQuery itself, such as [1](https://github.com/jducoeur/jquery-facade). You can then "pimp" additional methods provided by a jQuery plugin, such as jQuery mobile, using [the monkey patching pattern for Scala.js facades](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/calling-javascript.html):

```
import org.querky.jquery._

trait JQueryMobile extends JQuery {
  def navbar(): Unit
}

implicit def JQueryMobileOps(jQ: JQuery): JQueryMobile =
  jQ.asInstanceOf[JQueryMobile]
```

and then you can do:

```
$("[data-role='navbar']").navbar()
```

and it will be statically typechecked.